# Why does pstack launch gdb (and how to prevent it)?

Tags: linux, process, gdb

Running pstack on a process sometimes causes gdb to attach to that process on one of my Linux servers.  Why would pstack launch gdb, and how can I prevent that?

Details:

- gdb is running as: `/user/bin/gdb --quiet -nx /proc/1234/exe 1234`
- the parent process of gdb is: `/bin/sh /user/bin/pstack 1234`

Comment: If you have frysk, you can run [fstack](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fstack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of `pstack` are standalone, but older versions (*e.g.* [`pstack-gdb`](https://oss.oracle.com/projects/pstack-gdb/), or the version of `pstack` in RHEL 5) are wrappers around `gdb`. Presumably “one of your servers” has an older distribution and its version of `pstack` is one of the `gdb` wrappers.

To prevent that, you’d have to install a [newer version of `pstack`](https://code.lm7.fr/robotux/pstack).

Comment: With this guidance, I noticed that "head -1 /bin/pstack" reveals "#!/bin/sh". It turns out that pstack is a short shell script on my RHEL7 system.